# How to make injected objectmapper output locale-specific

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Spring Boot REST controller with the method

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/validate", produces = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public Result validate(
      @ApiParam(value = "http://example.org/test", required = true) @RequestParam String iri,
      @Context HttpServletRequest request
  ) {
    return service.validate(iri);
  }
...
```

And a custom object mapper configured as (`Result` class is part of a third-party library)

```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Result.class, new ResultSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper;
  }
```

Inside `ResultSerializer` (my custom implementation) I need to customize the serialization output based on the `Accept-language` header (e.g. from the bounding HttpServletRequest). I am currently only able to solve by not using Spring injection for the `ObjectMapper`, explicitly creating an ObjectMapper instance in my controller, executing it and returning the output. So:

**Can an `Accept-language` header be obtained in the `ObjectMapper` instance injected as a Spring bean?**

Comment: What specifically are you attempting to customize?

Comment: I am trying to change ObjectMapper's behaviour based on a parameter in request (in this case Accept-Language header). My problem is that ObjectMapper examples are not request scoped, so I am not sure how to pass the incoming HTTP request header as a parameter to them.

Comment: What behavior _specifically_ are you trying to change? This is not best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility (not knowing exactly what you are trying to customize): You could try making your ResultSerializer `request-scoped`.

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public ResultSerializer resultSerializer() {
    return new ResultSerializer();
}
```

Then you can simply inject your HttpServletRequest into the ResultSerializer.

```
public class ResultSerializer {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marco, I managed to adjust slightly his solution to get it working using:

```
 @Bean
 @RequestScope
 public ObjectMapper objectMapper(@Autowired HttpServletRequest request) {
     ...
     module.addSerializer(Result.class, new ResultSerializer(request.getLocale().toLanguageTag()));
     ...
 }
```